# TYPO3: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I'm experimenting a bit with TYPO3 backend modules and I'm trying to get a view when I click my module in the left menu in the backend. However when I click this I get the following message:

> Sorry, the requested view was not found.
>   The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "list" in class "MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\ConnectionController".

I have the view for the list action in the folder Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/Connection and the file is called List.html (uppercamelcase)

I'm using TYPO3 version 7.6.15 and I made this module with the extension builder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some possible reasons for this (or similar) errors:

### 1. Forgetting to include the TypoScript static templates

- see Documentation: [Include TypoScript from extensions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Entering.html#include-typoscript-from-extensions)

  1. Choose *WEB > Template* module (in Module menu)
  2. Select your start (root) page (in page tree)
  3. Select *Info / Modify* (in Docheader)
  4. Choose *Edit the whole template record*
  5. Choose tab *Includes*
  6. Select your extension under *Available Items*

This will activate the TypoScript under Configuration/TypoScript

[image]

### 2. Wrong path

The Template paths set via TypoScript must match the available template paths in the filesystem.

Usually, the default path is:

- Resources/Private/Templates (for frontend plugins)

or

- Resources/Private/Backend/Templates (for backend modules)

This must have been set correctly via TypoScript. For example:

Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript:

```
# Module configuration
module.tx_myexample_web_myexamplelist {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:myexample/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
...
```

- module. is for backend modules
- if you are working with frontend plugins, use plugin. instead of module.
- the correct file ending for TypoScript [is .typoscript since TYPO3 8](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.7.x/Feature-78161-IntroduceTypoScriptFileExtension.html) and no longer .ts or .txt. For version 7, it is correct to use .ts.

### 3. Incorrect filenames

Make sure that the name of the Controller matches the name of the subdirectory in the Templates directory. The name of the template file is capitalized.

- Controller/SomeController.php: listAction()

matches

- Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/Some/List.html

---

Where to define the TS:

- either as described above e.g. in Configuration/TypoScript setup.typoscript (and load this via static include).
- The file ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript in the extension root can be used to setup TypoScript independent of page-tree and template-records. This will be included in the setup section of all TypoScript templates. but also consider the warning in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-typoscript-setup-typoscript).
- Load TypoScript or TypoScript files directly in the extension with functions from ExtensionManagementUtility

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your template root path (the relative path from where the extension takes the tempaltes):

go to the

> setup.ts

file (or setup.txt file; depends on personal preferences and local configuration) and add the following line

```
plugin.tx_myslider.view.templateRootPath = EXT:path/to/custom/directory/
```

for example it could look like this:

```
EXT:slider/Resources/Private/Templates/myAwesomeFolder/
```

**NOTE: slider is just a placeholder. You can simply replace it with your extension name**

Comment: You are setting the path for (frontend) plugins. The question opener said that he is using (backend) modules. These are 2 different settings: plugin.tx_extkey.view.templateRootPaths or module.tx_extkey_module_submodule.view.templateRootPaths

Answer (score -2):

Add your extension to the website node. Until you add it, the setup.ts won't work.