# Typo3: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "list"

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

When I click on my module on the left I get this error message:

> Sorry, the requested view was not found.

The technical reason is:

> No template was found. View could not be resolved for action "list" in class "TYPO3\ShopExtension\Controller\ShopBackendController".

I have seen similar questions being asked here and I have tried all of their solutions, without success. For example:

[TYPO3: No template was found. View could not be resolved for action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229780/typo3-no-template-was-found-view-could-not-be-resolved-for-action)

I set the root paths for the templates, partials and layouts, in the constants.ts file in configuration directory as follows:

```
module.tx_shopextension {
        view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:shop_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/

        partialRootPath = EXT:shop_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/

        layoutRootPath = EXT:shop_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
     }
        persistence {
            # cat=module.tx_shopextension//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
            storagePid =
        }
    }
```

And use them in `setup.ts` like this:

```
# Module configuration
module.tx_shopextension {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_shopextension.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_shopextension.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_shopextension.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
  persistence {
    storagePid = {$module.tx_shopextension.persistence.storagePid}
  }
}
```

The templates are stored in:

```
Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
```

(same structur for Partials and Layouts)

In the `Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/` directory is a directory `ShopBackend` corresponding to the `ShopBackendController`, containing the `List.html` file.

I can't figure out why the error keeps popping up.

Comment: Hi. Maybe it's because you use the old-way. Try to use rootpaths as array: module.tx_shopextension.view.templateRootPaths.10 = EXT:shop_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/

Comment: It works, thank you! @JohannesC.Schulz 
If you formulate a complete answer, not as a comment, I will give you credit for it. You deserve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're using the old way for defining rootpath.
Please use the rootpath as array, like

```
 module.tx_shopextension.view.templateRootPaths.10 = EXT/shop_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but since I have less than 15 reputation, it won't be displayed here ;) Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Thanx a lot. The most important is, that it works for you! ;-)